# Bootstrap modal with back ground colour showing glitch in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

As you could see in the image even though the background is white it's still showing a. Transparent square patch any idea what is causing this?[image]

Comment: you need to reduce the `z-index` property for that square box

Comment: Tried but no luck